# How to pass variables to included tasks in ansible?

Tags: ansible

I have an ansible file (`my_file.yml`) that looks something like this:

```
---
- name: The name
  hosts: all
  tasks:

    - include:my_tasks.yml
      vars:
          my_var: "{{ my_var }}"
```

`my_tasks.yml` looks like this:

```
- name: Install Curl
  apt: pkg=curl state=installed

- name: My task
  command: bash -c "curl -sSL http://x.com/file-{{ my_var }} > /tmp/file.deb"
```

I'd like to pass `my_var` as a command-line argument to ansible so I do like this:

```
ansible-playbook my_file.yml --extra-vars "my_var=1.2.3"
```

But I end up with the following error:

```
... Failed to template {{ my_var }}: Failed to template {{ my_var }}: recursive loop detected in template string: {{ my_var }}
```

If I the `vars` in `my_file.yml` to look like this:

```
- include:my_tasks.yml
  vars:
      my_var: "1.2.3"
```

it works! I've also tried changing the variable name to something that is not equal to `my_var`, for example:

```
- include:my_tasks.yml
  vars:
      my_var: "{{ my_var0 }}"
```

but then I end up with an error. It seems to me that the variable is not expanded and instead the string `"{{ my_var }}"` or `{{ my_var0 }}` is passed to `my_tasks.yml`. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You shouldn't need to explicitly pass `my_var` to the `include`. All variables including extra-vars should be directly available everywhere. So simply calling

```
ansible-playbook my_file.yml --extra-vars "my_var=1.2.3"
```

and using it as `{{ my_var }}` in the tasks should work.

```
- name: My task
  command: bash -c "curl -sSL http://x.com/file-{{ my_var }} > /tmp/file.deb"
```

Comment: How can I pass a variable from a task (instead of setting the var in the playbook or at command line)?

Comment: What if I want to override the value of `my_var` when including?

Comment: extra-vars cannot be overridden. They always take precedence. https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#understanding-variable-precedence

Answer (score 37):

Faced the same issue in my project. It turns out that the variable name in the playbook and the task have to be different.

```
---
- name: The name
  hosts: all
  vars:
    my_var_play: "I need to send this value to the task"
    some_other_var: "This is directly accessible in task"
  tasks:
    - include:my_tasks.yml
      vars:
          my_var: "{{ my_var_play }}"
```

Also on a sidenote, all the variables in the playbook is accessible in the task. Just use `{{ some_other_var }}` in task and it should work fine.

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly what I needed!